# Fire query on condition basis. if "All" then need to get all data from view but if value is different than data should be that value based

Tags: db2

I am new to DB2. Please help me resolve my issues.

I need to fire sql query in DB2 on condition basis. 
Like if the value is "All" then I need to get all data from view but if value is something else than data should be on the basis of that value.

Example:

```
SELECT 
     M.Col1, 
     M.Col2, 
     M.Col3
FROM   
     view M
WHERE 
     M.Col1 = {?param} and
     D.Col2 = '{?paramC}'
```

---

Now 
if ?paramC is 'All' then the then query should be

```
SELECT 
     M.Col1, 
     M.Col2, 
     M.Col3
FROM   
     view M
WHERE 
     M.Col1 = {?param}      // means ?paramC is rejected if All is selected

else
SELECT 
     M.Col1, 
     M.Col2, 
     M.Col3
FROM   
     view M
WHERE 
     M.Col1 = {?param} and
     D.Col2 = '{?paramC}'      // means if ?paramC is some value like 1,2,3 etc
```

Hope I am clear on my question. I am stuck here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT M.Col1, M.Col2, M.Col3 FROM
view M WHERE M.Col1 = {?param} and (D.Col2 = '{?paramC}' or '{?paramC}' = 'All')
```